# Широкий слайдер на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, есть вот такой вот слайдер:)

И как бы всё ок, на пк отключен скролл горизонтальный и всё выглядит адекватно.

Но на моб и планшетах можно пальцем прокрутить экран на всю ширину слайдера(3000 пикселей) Как ограничить слайдер по ширине?

```
codepen.io/alexandr-dorohin-the-reactor/pen/WNvJdvz?editors=1111
```

(тут код не смог прикрепить, пишет, что пост по большей части состоит из кода, и нужно добавить больше текста:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В body
    overflow-x: hidden
было прописано вот такое

А добавление вот такого решило проблему:
.testimonials
    overflow: hidden

Answer (score 0):

```
html,
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Был прописан в боди.

Comment: Добавил .testimonials
    overflow: hidden и заработало